# How to upload SWF source files in Moodle 3.8?

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle, Using moodle. 3.8.2. How to upload flash source content in moodle.

Please help.

Regards
Girija

Answer (score 0):

You can include a swf file within the editor, just like adding photos.

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Media_embedding

But you will probably need to enable the media filter for Flash.

Go to Site admin > Plugins >Media players > Manage media players > Enable flash animation

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Media_FAQ#Why_won.27t_my_swf_video_play.3F